# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() due to var_dump is null

Tags: php, codeigniter, null, var-dump

Yesterday when I `var_dump($this->m_test->result_getGrades());`it gave me an array[1356] now it returned null. Can anyone help me figure out why it's NULL? I'm still new in PHP and Codeigniter and its pretty stressful figuring out why I can't retrieve any data from my database.

I assume the reason why I have this error because `($this->m_test->result_getGrades())` is NULL

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: views/v_display.php
>
> Line Number: 7

Also, What are the factors why I can't retrieve any data from my database? For future references

This is my code:

Controller c_test.php

```
function getGrades() {
       $data['query'] = $this->m_test->result_getGrades(); 
       $this->load->view('v_display', $data);
    }
```

Model m_test.php

```
function result_getGrades()
    {
          $this->db->select('grades.blockcode,subjectblocking.subjectcode,subjects.description,grades.final');
          $this->db->from('grades');
          $this->db->join('subjectblocking','grades.blockcode=subjectblocking.blockcode');
          $this->db->join('subjects','subjectblocking.subjectcode=subject.subjectcode');
          $this->db->where('2013-F019');
          $query=$this->db->get();          
    }
```

Views v_display.php

```
<?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>

               <?php echo $row->studentid;?><br>
               <?php echo $row->subjectcode;?><br>
               <?php echo $row->description;?><br>
               <?php echo $row->final;?><br>


         <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thank you once again! :)

Comment: I don't know CodeIgniter but maybe you get the NULL because of the query itself, maybe the where condition or the joins are causing that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many faults in your `result_getGrades()` function :

```
function result_getGrades()
{
    $this->db->select('grades.blockcode,subjectblocking.subjectcode,subjects.description,grades.final');
    $this->db->from('grades');
    $this->db->join('subjectblocking','grades.blockcode=subjectblocking.blockcode');
    $this->db->join('subjects','subjectblocking.subjectcode = subjects.subjectcode');
    $this->db->where('your_field', '2013-F019');

    $query = $this->db->get()->result();

    return $query;        
}
```

There was :

- add the `return $query;`
- `field name` in your where clauses
- `subject` to `subjects` in your join

Comment: it still gave me an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object`

Comment: I think this `$this->db->where('2013-F019');` is false, the syntax of where clause is `$this->db->where('yourcolum', 'yourvalue');`

Comment: okay, i tried the querying it without the where clause its still the same

Comment: At the line `$this->db->join('subjects','subjectblocking.subjectcode=subject.subjectcode');`, replace `subject` to `subjects`

Answer (score 3):

You should try this:

First, you will need to check your `where` clause.

see example below:

```
$this->db->where('name', 'test');
```

that will produce `WHERE name = 'test'` in the MySQL query

then you have to put a return statement after your `get()` method:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

so your model should be something like this:

```
function result_getGrades()
{
      $this->db->select('grades.blockcode,subjectblocking.subjectcode,subjects.description,grades.final');
      $this->db->from('grades');
      $this->db->join('subjectblocking','grades.blockcode=subjectblocking.blockcode');
      $this->db->join('subjects','subjectblocking.subjectcode=subject.subjectcode');

      $this->db->where('name of field', '2013-F019');

      $query=$this->db->get();  

      return $query->result_array();        
}
```

Comment: I removed the where clause and added the `return $query->result_array();` however an error occured such as ` Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object`

Answer (score 1):

var dumping the query itself usually doesn't return much for me usually but it depends on when you dump it.

```
<?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>

           <?php echo $row->studentid;?><br>
           <?php echo $row->subjectcode;?><br>
           <?php echo $row->description;?><br>
           <?php echo $row->final;?><br>


     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

For this you don't need to keep opening and closing the php tags unless you want alot of html around it:

```
<?php foreach ($query as $row){

           echo $row->studentid.'<br>';
           echo $row->subjectcode.'<br>';
           echo $row->description.'<br>';
           echo $row->final.'<br>';


     }?>
```

Notice the . ? It joins the $row->studentid to the html meaning it's alot cleaner code.

Now onto the question, you're assigning a variable as a variable in your foreach...Which is pointless. Thankfully i know the fix. You need to turn the query into a result from your database:

```
<?php foreach ($query->result() as $row){

           echo $row->studentid.'<br>';
           echo $row->subjectcode.'<br>';
           echo $row->description.'<br>';
           echo $row->final.'<br>';


     }?>
```

`$query->result() as $row` will enable you to echo out the information you get back from the database.

Also at the end of the model, you need to add `return $query;` otherwise your model is getting the data and not doing anything with it.

Comment: added the `return $query->result_array();` however an error occured such as ` Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object`

Comment: Do you have `$this->load->database` in your construct on every model/controller this uses?